# Nodejs y MySQL: LOAD DATA INFILE manda error "No such file or directory"

Tags: mysql, nodejs, data, filesystem

Quiero hacer un LOAD FILE de Mysql desde Nodejs pero obtengo un error

```
{ Error: EE_STAT: Can't get stat of '/var/www/node/importacion/api/csv_files/bulk_for_mysql_410201713121.txt' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

Mi script es el siguiente:

```
conexion.query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/node/importacion/api/csv_files/"+archivo+"' INTO TABLE cuentas FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';", function(err, rows, fields){
   if(err){
     reject(err);
   }
   console.log(rows);
   resolve();
});
```

El fichero txt sí está en esa ruta

Comment: El archivo puede estar en la ruta, pero el proceso que hace el `LOAD FILE` tiene los permisos adecuados para poder acceder al archivo? Es probable que requiera un acceso exclusivo por lo que posiblemente intente bloquearlo, trata de darle al usuario que inicia el proceso los permisos más completos posibles.

Comment: prueba via consola hacer esta accion!

Comment: Sí, tengo todos los permisos, incluso ese .txt es generado instantes previos al LOAD DATA de MySQL. He logrado hacer la inserción modificando la consulta al incluir la palabra "LOCAL" en esta línea utilizando Mysqlworkbench, pero no lo consigo aún con Nodejs.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/node/importacion/api/csv_files/bulk_for_mysql_4102017125519.txt' INTO TABLE cuentas FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';